# find_if in MFC container with iterator derived from std::iterator

Tags: collections, stl, mfc, iterator, c++

I have a [<strike>working iterator</strike>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070098/stl-iterator-for-mfc-container-coblist) for MFC CObList - `BaseMFCIter`. It works for iterating in loop but i still didn't managed to make `ListIter` to work properly with STL algorithm find_if.
Code

```
#include < iterator >
#include "afxwin.h"
#include "afxtempl.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib> 
class myCObject : public CObject
{
public:
    myCObject( std::string val )
    {
        x = val;
    }
    std::string x;
};
template < typename Item, class Cont, class Key = POSITION >
class BaseMFCIter : public std::iterator < std::input_iterator_tag, Item >
{
public:
    // Define types for the 2 member functions to be used:
    typedef Key  (Cont::*GetFirstFunctionPtr) ()     const;
    typedef Item    (Cont::*GetNextFunctionPtr)  (Key&) const;


    // Default constructor, makes a null iterator, equal to BaseMFCIter::end()
    BaseMFCIter() : m_pCont(0), m_Pos(0), m_GetFirstFunc(0), m_GetNextFunc(0), m_End(true) {}

    // Constructor taking pointer to container and the iteration functions
    BaseMFCIter(Cont* pCont, GetFirstFunctionPtr pFF, GetNextFunctionPtr pNF) 
        : m_pCont(pCont), m_Pos(0), m_GetFirstFunc(pFF), m_GetNextFunc(pNF)
    { init(); }

    // Copy constructor, initialises iterator to first element
    BaseMFCIter(const BaseMFCIter& vi) : m_pCont(vi.m_pCont), m_Pos(0),
        m_GetFirstFunc(vi.m_GetFirstFunc), m_GetNextFunc(vi.m_GetNextFunc)
    { init(); }

    // Assignment operator, initialises iterator to first element
    BaseMFCIter& operator=(const BaseMFCIter& vi)
    {
        m_pCont     = vi.m_pCont; 
        m_GetFirstFunc  = vi.m_GetFirstFunc;
        m_GetNextFunc   = vi.m_GetNextFunc;
        init();  
        return *this; 
    }

    bool operator == (const BaseMFCIter& rhs) const
    { return (m_Pos == rhs.m_Pos && m_End == rhs.m_End); }

    bool operator != (const BaseMFCIter& rhs) const 
    { return !operator==(rhs); }

    BaseMFCIter&    operator ++ ()    { advance(); return *this; }
    BaseMFCIter&    operator ++ (int) { BaseMFCIter ret(*this); advance(); return ret; }
    Item            operator *  ()    { return m_Item; }
    Item            operator -> ()    { return m_Item; }

    static BaseMFCIter end   ()    { return BaseMFCIter(); }    // end() returns default null iterator

private:
    Item     m_Item;      // Current item from container
    Cont* m_pCont;     // Pointer to container
    Key  m_Pos;       // Key to item in container
    bool     m_End;       // Flag to indicate end of container reached

    // Pointers to container iteration functions
    GetFirstFunctionPtr m_GetFirstFunc;
    GetNextFunctionPtr  m_GetNextFunc;

    // Use container GetFirst & GetNext functions to set to first element, or end() if not found
    void init() 
    {
        m_Pos = 0;
        m_End = true;

        if (m_pCont && m_GetFirstFunc != 0)
        {
            m_Pos = (m_pCont->*m_GetFirstFunc)();
            advance();
        }
    }

    // Use container GetNext function to find next element in container
    void advance()
    {
        m_End = m_Pos ? false : true;
        m_Item = (m_Pos && m_pCont && m_GetNextFunc != 0) ? 
            (m_pCont->*m_GetNextFunc)(m_Pos) : Item();
    }
};
    struct Container : public CObList
    {
        myCObject*       GetNext(POSITION& rPosition)
        {
            return dynamic_cast<myCObject*>(CObList::GetNext(rPosition));
        }
        myCObject const* GetNext(POSITION& rPosition) const
        { 
            return dynamic_cast<const myCObject*>(CObList::GetNext(rPosition)); 
        }
    };


    class ListIter : public BaseMFCIter < const myCObject*, Container, POSITION  >
    {
    public:
        ListIter( Container* pObj = 0)  
            : BaseMFCIter< const myCObject*, Container, POSITION >
                (pObj, &CObList::GetHeadPosition, &Container::GetNext)
        {
        }
    };

    struct Comparator
    {
        std::string stringToCompare;
        bool operator() ( const myCObject* lhs )
        {
            return (bool) lhs->x.compare( stringToCompare );
        }
    };

    void main( )
    {


        myCObject* m = new myCObject( "one" );
        myCObject* n = new myCObject( "two" );
        myCObject* p = new myCObject( "three" );
        myCObject* q = new myCObject( "four" );

        Container cont;
        cont.AddHead( m );
        cont.AddHead( n );
        cont.AddHead( p );
        cont.AddHead( q );

        Comparator pred;
        pred.stringToCompare = "1";
        ListIter iter = ListIter( &cont );
        ListIter endIter = ListIter( );
        ListIter foundIter = std::find_if( iter, endIter, pred );

        std::cout << "foundIter x is: " << foundIter->x.c_str() << std::endl;

    }
```

gives me `foundIter x is: four`. This propably happens because of the way the end position is defined so

```
_InIt _Find_if(_InIt _First, _InIt _Last, _Pr _Pred)
    {   // find first satisfying _Pred
    _DEBUG_RANGE(_First, _Last);
    _DEBUG_POINTER(_Pred);
    for (; _First != _Last; ++_First)
        if (_Pred(*_First))
            break;
    return (_First);
    }
```

doesn't iterate properly but i can't figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A number of issues fixed:

- `(bool) lhs->x.compare( stringToCompare )` returns true _whenever the string **don't** match** (see [`string::compare`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/))
- you were searching for "1", which doesn't exist
- since the predicate was wrong, you received the first match, which was the first element, also inserted the last, and the name was `"four"` :)
- you didn't check whether a valid match was found (dereferencing the end-iterator is illegal and may crash your program or do worse things: undefined behaviour)
- you had a superflous `x.c_str()` in the output statement
- I changed the `Compare` predicate around to be more idiomatic:

  - initialize `stringToCompare` from the constructor
  - make the field `const`
  - make the `operator()` a `const` method

This should do the trick <strike>(untested code, I'm not near a compiler the coming hours)</strike>

### **Update**

After arriving home, I finally broke out the debugger to track that strange behaviour (see comments).

To my dismay, I found out that the `BaseMFCIter` was designed by someone with very limited understanding of what an iterator *is*: **the copy constructor and assignment operator were completely wrong**: they had the effect of creating a new `begin` iterator - for the same collection. This however, means that an iterator could never be returned from a function.

Therefore, I fixed it (first by implementing it right, later by removing the now-redundant constructor and operator= in favour of the compiler-generated default implementations).

#### *See the [full history of my and your edits](https://gist.github.com/1353471):*

```
git clone git://gist.github.com/1353471.git
```

- sehe 11 minutes ago   rely on default generated copy constructor and assignment instead
- sehe 12 minutes ago   fixed broken copy constructor and assignment
- sehe 65 minutes ago   tentative
- Dmitry 73 minutes ago Attempt at find_if with predicate
- sehe Heeren 25 hours   ago Fixed and Tested (VS2010)
- sehe 25 hours ago ( [STL iterator for MFC container CObList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070098/stl-iterator-for-mfc-container-coblist) )

```
#include "afxwin.h"
#include "afxtempl.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

class myCObject : public CObject
{
public:
    myCObject( const std::string& val ) { x = val; }
    std::string x;
};

template < typename Item, class Cont, class Key = POSITION >
class BaseMFCIter : public std::iterator < std::input_iterator_tag, Item >
{
public:
    // Define types for the 2 member functions to be used:
    typedef Key  (Cont::*GetFirstFunctionPtr) ()     const;
    typedef Item    (Cont::*GetNextFunctionPtr)  (Key&) const;

    // Default constructor, makes a null iterator, equal to BaseMFCIter::end()
    BaseMFCIter() : m_pCont(0), m_Pos(0), m_GetFirstFunc(0), m_GetNextFunc(0), m_End(true) {}

    // Constructor taking pointer to container and the iteration functions
    BaseMFCIter(Cont* pCont, GetFirstFunctionPtr pFF, GetNextFunctionPtr pNF) 
        : m_pCont(pCont), m_Pos(0), m_GetFirstFunc(pFF), m_GetNextFunc(pNF)
    { init(); }

    bool operator == (const BaseMFCIter& rhs) const
    { return (m_Pos == rhs.m_Pos && m_End == rhs.m_End); }

    bool operator != (const BaseMFCIter& rhs) const 
    { return !operator==(rhs); }

    BaseMFCIter&    operator ++ ()    { advance(); return *this; }
    BaseMFCIter&    operator ++ (int) { BaseMFCIter ret(*this); advance(); return ret; }
    Item            operator *  ()    { return m_Item; }
    Item            operator -> ()    { return m_Item; }

    static BaseMFCIter end   ()    { return BaseMFCIter(); }    // end() returns default null iterator

private:
    Item  m_Item;   // Current item from container
    Cont* m_pCont;  // Pointer to container
    Key   m_Pos;    // Key to item in container
    bool  m_End;    // Flag to indicate end of container reached

    // Pointers to container iteration functions
    GetFirstFunctionPtr m_GetFirstFunc;
    GetNextFunctionPtr  m_GetNextFunc;

    // Use container GetFirst & GetNext functions to set to first element, or end() if not found
    void init() 
    {
        m_Pos = 0;
        m_End = true;

        if (m_pCont && m_GetFirstFunc != 0)
        {
            m_Pos = (m_pCont->*m_GetFirstFunc)();
            advance();
        }
    }

    // Use container GetNext function to find next element in container
    void advance()
    {
        m_End = m_Pos ? false : true;
        m_Item = (m_Pos && m_pCont && m_GetNextFunc != 0) ? 
            (m_pCont->*m_GetNextFunc)(m_Pos) : Item();
    }
};

struct Container : public CObList
{
    myCObject* GetNext(POSITION& rPosition)
    {
        return dynamic_cast<myCObject*>(CObList::GetNext(rPosition));
    }
    myCObject const* GetNext(POSITION& rPosition) const
    { 
        return dynamic_cast<const myCObject*>(CObList::GetNext(rPosition)); 
    }
};


class ListIter : public BaseMFCIter < const myCObject*, Container, POSITION  >
{
public:
    ListIter( Container* pObj = 0)  
        : BaseMFCIter< const myCObject*, Container, POSITION >
            (pObj, &CObList::GetHeadPosition, &Container::GetNext)
    {
    }
};

struct Comparator
{
    Comparator(const std::string& compareTo) : stringToCompare(compareTo) {}

    bool operator() ( const myCObject* lhs ) const
    {
        return 0 == lhs->x.compare( stringToCompare );
    }
  private:
    const std::string stringToCompare;
};

void main( )
{
    myCObject* m = new myCObject( "one" );
    myCObject* n = new myCObject( "two" );
    myCObject* p = new myCObject( "three" );
    myCObject* q = new myCObject( "four" );

    Container cont;
    cont.AddHead( m );
    cont.AddHead( n );
    cont.AddHead( p );
    cont.AddHead( q );

    Comparator pred("three");
    ListIter iter = ListIter(&cont),
             endIter = ListIter( );

    ListIter foundIter = std::find_if( iter, endIter, pred );

    if (endIter != foundIter)
    {
        std::cout << "foundIter x is: " << foundIter->x << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "not found" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Added a point-by-point explanation of things changed/fixed (thus, explaining why you got the `"four"` result, before) (**edit** fixed a bug)

Comment: If i don't use x.c_str( ) i get an error. Error 1 error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: @Dmitry: huh. That's strange. Try `#include <string>`. Is that with VS2008? And with the standard (Dinkumware) STL implementation? Amazing.

Comment: Yes, its vs2008. It should be standard - i didn't change anything manualy. By the way, here is what i get when i step into find_if: http://imgur.com/a/1WtM9#0 . In find_if it iterates and finds "three" CObject object and then returns a value, but when it gives control to _InIt, _First changes m_Item.x value from "Three" to "Four" for some reason.

Comment: @Dmitry: why do you care what goes on inside these algorithms? As long as they honour the contracts... **`m_Item` is private for a reason**. So, `BaseMFCIter` times it's iterator advances surprisingly (implementation detail), however, `ListIters` are returned by value, so the value `find_if` had returned will stay the same

Comment: I agree, i was just trying to guess why this happens ). Nevertheless i get "four" even if i search by value that is not in cont.

Comment: Aha. That is surprising. That means the test `endIter != foundIter` isn't working. I'll try to investigate after 2300H CET

Comment: Hi Dmitry I fixed the problem. It was a very strange problem with the iterator copy contructor/assignment. As the comment said, it would always reset the iterator on copy (???). That is just braindead. So, the start of your question (`I have a working iterator for MFC CObList`) was a wrong assumption. I fixed it by actually implementing copy and assignment. Note that since the m_Item is cached by value, the iterator is very likely to only work with well pointers (in the spirit of CObList, I guess). **Hold on** editing post.

Comment: Hi Dmitry I fixed the problem. It was a very strange problem with the iterator copy contructor/assignment. As the comment said, it would always reset the iterator on copy (???). That is just braindead. So, the start of your question (`I have a working iterator for MFC CObList`) was a wrong assumption. I fixed it by actually implementing copy and assignment. Note that since the m_Item is cached by value, the iterator is very likely to only work with well pointers (in the spirit of CObList, I guess). **Edited answer with code, explanation**

Comment: Thank you, that works. Now i can rewrite the rest of the project. Crossed out "Working" in the question.